# No /etc/fstab folder to amend swap issue

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I was given an answer earlier on how to correct a swap file issue. Now however, I discover that I have no /etc/fstab folder in my file system to alter. I have a /etc/fstab.d folder but it is empty. I am able to boot up (GRUB2) with the only issue being my swap file doesn't load at boot up and has to be loaded with GParted manually. The prior answer indicated "(It's got a swap device with the same name :-) " and suggested I amend my /etc/fstab folder. When I try in the terminal as SUDO I get a denied permission response and then discovered the /etc/fstab issue. Any suggestions or am I better off backing up my home directories and partion the drive for both Mint Xfce and Mate again?

Update: I found the fstab file as a txt file in the etc folder it isa mess

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b1f19883-53c5-4f12-9220-e8ffadfcb29d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=21286226-9a42-46ed-b421-b44cb4342715 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question](http://superuser.com/q/997773/83694)?  `/etc/fstab` is a regular file, not a folder, and [it must exist or your system would not boot](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/61645-ect-fstab-doesnt-exist-post329762.html?s=ad8fb7d1e0d640af137000cf83288a96#post329762).  I know for sure that Linux Mint 17.2 has `/etc/fstab` because I've modified its `/etc/fstab` file before.

Comment: Yes. I am hunting for the etc/fstab file since I have GRUB2 working and can boot off it to either Mint 17.2 Xfce or Mate. Is it possible it is mislabelled (doubt it). I have tried looking in the hidden folders to no avail.

Comment: Found fstab as a txt file and looks like this (a mess):

Comment: That's a normal `/etc/fstab`.  Just replace the last line of what you pasted with [what I suggested](http://superuser.com/a/997800/83694), and SWAP will be set up.

Comment: @Deltik, you should post that as an aswer

Comment: [Done](http://superuser.com/a/997996/83694), @cristi

Comment: It's a root file and you may not see it if you look as a non-root user.  Editting it must be done as root.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a full answer expanded from [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/997886/no-etc-fstab-folder-to-amend-swap-issue?noredirect=1#comment1378566_997886) as [suggested by cristi](https://superuser.com/questions/997886/no-etc-fstab-folder-to-amend-swap-issue?noredirect=1#comment1378732_997886).*

*This question is a follow-up to [Swap file automatic loading in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/997773/83694).*

---

`/etc/fstab` is a regular file, not a folder, and [it must exist or your system would not boot](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/61645-ect-fstab-doesnt-exist-post329762.html?s=ad8fb7d1e0d640af137000cf83288a96#post329762).

I see that [you were later able to find the `/etc/fstab` file](https://superuser.com/revisions/997886/2).

### Solution

Replace the last line of `/etc/fstab` (reproduced below):

```
UUID=21286226-9a42-46ed-b421-b44cb4342715 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

… with this line instead:

```
/dev/sda5 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

### Explanation

It sounds like you may have removed and recreated the SWAP partition `/dev/sda5`, which changes the UUID that the `/etc/fstab` was using to find the SWAP partition at the time of the operating system installation.

Instead of identifying the SWAP partition as `UUID=21286226-9a42-46ed-b421-b44cb4342715`, `/dev/sda5` is the SWAP partition as we know it from your setup.

#### Caveat

**`/dev/sda5` is not guaranteed to identify the SWAP partition.**  If you insert another hard drive into your computer, `/dev/sda5` might become `/dev/sdb5`.

You can go back to using the UUID by finding the new UUID of your SWAP partition.  This command can give you the new UUID:

```
blkid | grep 'TYPE="swap"'
```

If your new UUID is `f95e5378-6b56-4369-80ea-1845313041c8`, you should use this as your new `/etc/fstab` line for SWAP:

```
UUID=f95e5378-6b56-4369-80ea-1845313041c8 none            swap    sw              0       0
```